# About the healthy situation of one plant ( maybe Cyperaceae type)

Tags: plant-health, sunlight

I have seen one sick plant in one Japanese company office in my country and I have tried to find out its problem. The picture of this plant can be seen below:

[image: Pot plant with yellowing long, thin leaves]

[image: Wider view of the plant]

I have tried to find out its type by Google reverse engine as you can see at [this link](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisse1cmSYpM8s2AJUocNFVi-kQeCm7D_1osFrVcjbqwdkI8c2hZXOZuVsIETxWZwOkvcqaka10aJYkq-6Cp7WIlqsY-ah8mtZprXMfSXqK9EUDLKBRODvQCLHDNHi2spIgklhCe0rjVQfL4DouvZ7cu3sZ1ph4GTKhh0JFEMAOb9GIEj4Om-RVzGya2ObDfVQMoU1ewfLtJdeWJlILA8JK7nT7EJQdPrSYgrcQ7azlgc9Ih3JqUeUqmMIiK7sqgIDYr-QJIXigpLWLZqSP8MRIrqUQJl6NgeOzhuRjEOqosm6bHSoRCkvvL6a7hZf7XIk109jp0_12cLtSNyOCoxdGk4ijgwKvw&hl=fa) and google said it is one plant from the [Cyperaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyperaceae) type.

This plant don't have the sun light and I guess that is it's problem.  I don't know why its green color is reduced. I was thinking when one plant don't get enough sun light it must become more green to get more energy form the light and the green color of this plant is reduced vice versa.

If possible I would like to know about its health condition and the possible cure for it.